# Javascript shopping cart help needed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, shopping-cart

I have a gridview with a list of products and need to add these to a javascript shopping cart.
Using the following code this works perfectly:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="simpleCart.add( 'name=<%# Eval("Name") %>' , 'price=<%# Eval("Price") %>' , 'quantity=1' );">Add To Cart</a>
```

However, I also need to perform some server-side functions when a product is added to cart so I thought of replacing the above with a button and calling onClick and onClientClick like so:

```
<asp:Button ID="AddCartButton" runat="server" Text="Add To Cart" onClick="AddCartButton_Click" OnClientClick="AddItem()" />
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function Additem() {
                        javascript: simpleCart.add('name=<%# Eval("Name") %>', 'price=<%# Eval("Price") %>', 'quantity=1');
                    }    
    </script>
```

This doesn't produce any errors, but the javascript doesn't seem to be working (as no products are added to the cart), however the server-side code is executing properly.

Comment: How are you messaging the server once an item is added to the cart?

Comment: Yeah, the button will cause a post back, unless the data grid id ajax enabled, the client call is really pointless.

Comment: The cart is completely done in javascript, I got it from http://simplecartjs.com/ . But I also need to add server side functionality (access the database), and doing it this way seemed to be the easiest method since I know some C# but am completely new to asp.net/javascript etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the onClientClick to this:

```
<asp:Button ID="AddCartButton" runat="server" Text="Add To Cart" onClick="AddCartButton_Click" 
     OnClientClick='<%# Eval("Name", "AddItem(\"{0}\", ").ToString() + Eval("Price", "\"{0}\")").ToString() %>' />
```

And the function to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function Additem(name, price) {
                    javascript: simpleCart.add('name=' + name, 'price=' + price, 'quantity=1');
                }    
            </script>
```

As Samich provided above.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you are creating a lot of global functions and it will be used only latest one. Provide your data with params to this function and declare it only once on the page.

Change to:

```
<asp:Button ID="AddCartButton" runat="server" Text="Add To Cart" onClick="AddCartButton_Click" OnClientClick="AddItem('<%# Eval("Name") %>', '<%# Eval("Price") %>')" />
```

and outside of data boundind:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function Additem(name, price) {
                    javascript: simpleCart.add('name=' + name, 'price=' + price, 'quantity=1');
                }    
            </script>
```

Comment: Since you posted this first, I will delete my answer.

Comment: I now get the following error:
Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

Comment: Try to change attribute to following: `OnClientClick='<%# "AddItem(" + Eval("Name") + ", " + Eval("Price") + ");" %>'`